# HTML hover shifting other parts of a page when hovered upon

Tags: html, css, hover

Here I have an image gallery that works all fine, however when the smaller images are selected the hover appears to shift all the small images down a bit, which appears to move the entire page which is annoying. I'm assuming it's something to do with margin or padding, and I've tried many combination's with little success. Here is the code:

HTML

```
<div class="gallery_thumbnails">
  <div class="imagebox">
    <img onclick="preview.src=img1.src" name="img1" src="images/IMAGE GALLERY 1.png" alt="">
    <div class="text">HomeLobby</div>
  </div>

  <div class="imagebox">
    <img onclick="preview.src=img2.src" name="img2" src="images/IMAGE GALLERY 2.png" alt="">
    <div class="text">HomeLobby</div>
  </div>

  <div class="imagebox">
    <img onclick="preview.src=img3.src" name="img3" src="images/IMAGE GALLERY 3.png" alt="">
    <div class="text">HomeLobby</div>
  </div>

  <div class="imagebox">
    <img onclick="preview.src=img4.src" name="img4" src="images/IMAGE GALLERY 4.png" alt="">
    <div class="text">HomeLobby</div>
  </div>

  <div class="imagebox">
    <img onclick="preview.src=img5.src" name="img5" src="images/IMAGE GALLERY 5.png" alt="">
    <div class="text">HomeLobby</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.image_gallery {padding-top: 10px;
                text-align: center;}

.gallery_thumbnails img {height: 60px;
                         width: 106px;}

.gallery_thumbnails img:hover {
                               border: 3px solid #a22b2f;
                               cursor: pointer;}

.gallery_thumbnails {position: relative;}

.imagebox {display: inline;}

.text {display: none;
       position: absolute;
       left: 140px;
       top: -30px;
       font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
       font-size: 16px;
       color: white;
       font-weight: 700;}

.imagebox img:hover + .text {display: block;}
```

Comment: First thing to do is rename the images without spaces in the file names.

Comment: So you are trying to move it down by adding a border on hover?

Comment: that's what I'm trying to avoid, I reckon I need some sort of margin, as the border is moving the smaller images down.

Comment: like a gap between the top of the smaller images or the bottom of the larger image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem happens because you are adding a border on hover which was not there before. This takes up space, so moves everything down to make room for the new border.

One solution is to add the same boder on the normal unhovered state, but give it a transparent colour, or the same colour as the background. This reserves the necessary space invisibly:

```
.gallery_thumbnails img {height: 60px;
                         width: 106px;
                         border: 3px solid transparent;
```

Another way is to use the outline property rather than a border (the syntax is the same):

```
.gallery_thumbnails img:hover {
                               outline: 3px solid #a22b2f;
                               cursor: pointer;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding a border on hover. This creates 3 extra px and pushes everything down. If your background is a solid color, add the same border to the element normally then on hover just change the color.

or even better... just add `box-sizing: border-box;` to the element and the border will take up space in the block and not create 3 extra px.

Answer (score 0):

Your border on hover is what's pushing down the elements, i'd suggest adding either

```
.gallery_thumbnails img:hover {
margin-top: -3px;
}
```

or

```
.gallery_thumbnails img { 
border: 3px solid transparent;
}
```